# Confusion 1D Bose-Hubbard Model Field-Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, phase-transition, superfluidity, bose-hubbard-model

**The General Setting**

I have some confusion concerning the interpretation of the field-theory describing the Bose-Hubbard Modell especialy in the one dimensional case.

The general framework of the action describing the critical behaviour is the following:
$$\mathcal{Z}_B = \int \mathcal{D}\Psi_B(x,\tau)\exp(-\int_0^{1/T}d\tau\int d^dx\mathcal{L}_B)$$
$$\mathcal{L}_B=\Psi_B^*\frac{\partial\Psi_B }{\partial \tau}+\frac{1}{2m}|\nabla \Psi_B|^2-\mu|\Psi_B|^2+\frac{u_0}{2}|\Psi_B|^4$$
This action can be derived from the original Hamiltonian which is explained in the [Sachdev Book on phase transitions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-phase-transitions/33C1C81500346005E54C1DE4223E5562).

This action describes the critical behaviour of the system and it was argued and shown that also for the $d=1$ case the predictions of the field theory hold (solving the perturbation theory in all orders in $u_0$). (e.g. in the [Sachdev Book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-phase-transitions/33C1C81500346005E54C1DE4223E5562), or in some original reference by [Fisher et al.](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.40.546)).

I know that in the $d=1$ case the $U(1)$ symmetry should not be broken spontaneously passing from the Mott-Insulator to the "superfluid" phase and one finds only a "quasi long-range order" in the superfluidity order parameter.

**My Confusion**

What puzzels me is the fact that for me the action $\mathcal L _B$ in my opinion describes a transition breaking $U(1)$ with a nonzero $<\Psi_B>=\neq 0$ and a symmetry borken phase.

**My Questions**

- What is the argumentation that the above action stil gives the right fixed point describing the transition in $d=1$ e.g. of a quantum $XY$-chain?
- Why is this action applicable despite it suggesting a $U(1)$ breaking that is prohibited?
- Am I wrong that this action is describing a $U(1)$ breaking?

Comment: There is a well-known theorem that a 1+1 dimensional quantum field theory with short-range interactions cannot spontaneously break a continuous internal symmetry: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01646487 . This theorem is called Coleman's theorem and is closely related to the Hohenberg-Mermin-Wagner theorem which concern finite temperature phase transitions. In any case this theorem shows that your $\mathcal{L}_B$ cannot have $U(1)$ symmetry breaking in one dimension, which is why one only has quasi long-range order.

Comment: Ok, I am aware of the Mermin-Wagner like prohibition of continuous symmetry breaking. My confusion comes from the fact that an action could describe both cases in depending on the dimension. I mean as you said in $1d$ the action does not describe a QPT with a symmetry broken phase, but in larger dimension it does. And both phase transitions are connected to the change of sign of the $\mu$. Can I read of the action which scenario is applicable, or do I need the extra input from the Mermin-Wagner theorem?

Comment: I mean one could quite easy see that the upper critical dimension of this action is $d=2$ and one can also quite easy perform a perturbative expansion to infinite order of the $u$-coupling renormalization and the self energy. Sachdev writes then in his book: "Furhter, the presence of a nonzero and universal interaction strength $u^*$ implies that the bosonic system is stable for the case $\mu>0$, because the repulsive interactions prevent condensation of an infinite density of bosons" ($u^*$ ist the value of the stable fixed point in the flow eq.)

Comment: For any $d<2$, you have an interacting theory with relevant interactions, and even though you can compute certain quantities to all orders in perturbation theory, it is not true that one can solve everything in perturbation theory. For example, one can perturbatively compute the expectation value of the field $\Psi_B$ and find it to be nonzero, in conflict with the theorem which says $\langle \Psi_B \rangle = 0$ in $d=1$. See also Sachdev's perturbative computation of the boson density at the end of Section 16.3.1.

Comment: Okey, i thin this is a useful insight. Do I understand it correctly , that the general statement would be, that although there are some observable e.g. self-energy which could be computed easily in all orders, there are other quantities which couldn‘t. One of them is the expectation value of the field (U(1) breaking order parameter). As calculating the field expectation value could Only be done order by order and we are starting the perturbative expansion around $d=2$ one obtains from the calculations always a finite value.

Comment: Yes, that's basically correct: if one formally considers dimensions $1<d<2$, one has symmetry breaking, but non-perturbative effects in $d=1$ alter this conclusion.

Comment: Also, you can attempt to use perturbation theory directly in $d=1$ in the ordered phase ($\mu$ large and positive), but in this case, if you *assume* that $\Psi_B$ acquires an expectation value, you will find that your perturbation expansion is unstable, and you will find IR divergent corrections to the leading-order results. You can see how this occurs in a different model in Section 6.2 of Sachdev.